# Angular material dialog - pass types into dialog component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7

I'm working on data driven app and currently I'm facing a problem of passing types into material angular dialog. I want to create reusable dialog form and need to change types for new dialog instance.

Is there a way to pass type into material dialog or into component? Or maybe there is possibility to create types in dialog itself from string passed as data?

I want to use types in dialog component like this (or similar):

```
export class DialogDynamicItemManagerDialog<T> {

    public dialogName: string;
    public items: Array<T>;
    public selectedItem: T;
    ...
}
```

I've tried to pass the type like this:

```
 OpenDynamicDialog(): void {
    this.dialog.open(DialogDynamicItemManagerDialog<MyType>, {
      data: {
        title: 'Manage items',
        items: this.items
      },
    });
}
```

but obviously it doesn't work.

I've also tried this:

```
 OpenDynamicDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogDynamicItemManagerDialog, {
      data: {
        title: 'Manage items',
        items: this.items,
        itemType: itemType
      },
    });
}
```

but I haven't find a way to change string into type in dialog afterwards.

Comment: You can avoid using generics using any insteadof T. Make DialogDynamicItemManagerDialog just a normal class with @Component decorator

Comment: Thank you for your answer! DialogDynamicItemManagerDialog is just normal component, with @Component decorator and unfortunately I want to pass type into it and not use type 'any'.

Answer (score 27):

**TL;DR:**

You can use the following code to specify the type that your dialog's data will use:

```
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open<MyDialogComponent, MyType>(MyDialogComponent, {
      data: {
        // Your data goes here
      }
    };
  }
}
```

In your dialog component:

```
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

export class MyDialogComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: MyType) { }
}
```

---

The `open` method of the `MatDialog` class actually allows three types to be specified (in order of sequence):

- `T`: The component class (optional - although there's no default value, you don't have to specify it if you're just calling the method without any other types)
- `D`: The type to be used for the data to be added to the dialog (optional - defaults to `any`)
- `R`: The type to be used for the result of the dialog (optional - defaults to `any`)

The method is defined as below:

```
  /**
   * Opens a modal dialog containing the given component.
   * @param componentOrTemplateRef Type of the component to load into the dialog,
   *     or a TemplateRef to instantiate as the dialog content.
   * @param config Extra configuration options.
   * @returns Reference to the newly-opened dialog.
   */
  open<T, D = any, R = any>(componentOrTemplateRef: ComponentType<T> | TemplateRef<T>,
          config?: MatDialogConfig<D>): MatDialogRef<T, R> {
    // ...
  }
```

The `D` type is then passed to `MatDialogConfig`, which accepts the same type to be used for the data to be passed in to the dialog.

---

*References:*

- [`MatDialog#open` source code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/1c74518e8ec78c77f472831c97efab23a2405298/src/material/dialog/dialog.ts#L121-L154) - notice how the types are passed around in the code!
- [`MatDialogConfig` source code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/1c74518e8ec78c77f472831c97efab23a2405298/src/material/dialog/dialog-config.ts#L31-L121) - notice how the class is defined!

Comment: Is there any way to type the data so as not to use the `any` as in: `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: any` ?

Comment: @Stephane You just use the same type as specified with the `D` type parameter in `MatDialog#open`.

Comment: I pass config and data so that makes me use the `any` type. I could get it to work like: `const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.hasBackdrop = true;
    dialogConfig.data = {
      soundtrack: existingSoundtrack
    };

    this.dialogRef = this.matDialog.open<SoundtrackDialogComponent>(SoundtrackDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
... @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: any
  ) {
    const inputSoundtrackEdition: SoundtrackEdition = data.soundtrack;`

Comment: Upvote this [feature request](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24538) to infer return-type `R` based on component passed into `MatDialog.open<T, D, R>()`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to have a typed dialog the way you outlined it. But what you can do is something like:

```
export class MyDialog {

    private savedForLater: SomeType;

    constructor(
            public containingDialog: MatDialogRef<MyDialog>,
            @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: SomeType) {

        this.savedForLater = data;
    }

}
```

Unfortunately when you launch the dialog the type isn't enforced so you could still do this

```
const dialogData = {} as SomeType
const fakeDialogData = {} as SomeOtherType
this.dialog.open(MyDialog, { data: dialogData });
this.dialog.open(MyDialog, { data: fakeDialogData }); // this compiles
```