# Expected expression at generic component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using material dialog in a component, when establishing a reference to it, the IDE shows me the error "SyntaxError: Expression expected".
What is the reason for this?

```
onDeleteClick(id: number): void {
    const data = this.getSomeData(id);
    const config: MatDialogConfig<ConfirmDeleteDialogConfig<SomeDTO>> = {
      data: {
        data,
        title: 'Sample text'
      }
    };

    if (data) {
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDeleteDialogComponent<SomeDTO>, config);
                                                                            //^ SyntaxError: Expression expected
      dialogRef
        .afterClosed()
        .pipe(...)
        .subscribe();
    }
  }
```

Class, config and dto:

```
export class ConfirmDeleteDialogComponent<T> {
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmDeleteDialogComponent<T>>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: T
  ) {}

}

export interface ConfirmDeleteDialogConfig<T> {
  data: T;
  title: string;
  text?: string;
}

export interface SomeDTO{ 
    name: string;
    id?: number;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're providing the *type* `ConfirmDeleteDialogComponent<SomeDTO>`.

Remove the generic to provide the class

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDeleteDialogComponent, config);
```

Comment: I need to pass a generic class to the dialogue because of the data typing I pass in the config.
If I understand the documentation correctly then the open() method can take a generic class:
`open<T, D = any, R = any>(**component: ComponentType<T>**, config?: MatDialogConfig<D>,): MatDialogRef<T, R>;`

Comment: Exactly. e.g. `this.dialog.open<ConfirmDeleteDialogComponent<SomeDTO>>(ConfirmDeleteDialogComponent, config);`  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57787741/4711754

Comment: But I'd be surprised if implicit typing didn't pick some of this anyway via typing config but check this.

Comment: OK, now i understand, this diamond notatnion right after method name worked and no more errors appeared, thank you.